# DialogFlow Actions on Google: Where can i find the Simulator as Speaker?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to [implement account linking with Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#enabling_account_linking)

When I connect via Actions on Google simulator,
I get this error:

> Simulator as Phone does not support linking account provided by the native mobile app. Please try on real phone or try Simulator as Speaker.

I am configuring Actions on Google with a company account. Unfortunately, my private phone has a different google account. So at the moment I do not know how to test the service on multiple devices.

Where can I find Simulator as Speaker?

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct tag? Please review it and possible edit your question to include the correct tags.

Comment: Actions on Google are part of a dialogflow: they are connected
There is no inherent tag on Actions on Google.
For this reason, I used dialogflow, which is the closest

Comment: They *can* be connected, but don't have to be. Actions on Google also has its own tag, which I have added.

Answer (score 1):

There are three icons to the right of the conversation transcript and above the debugging tabs. The middle icon, which looks like a speaker, is the one that you want.

[image]

However, this isn't likely to do what you want. Linking from a speaker is only possible if you are linking with the "Google Sign In for the Assistant" method. If you are, great. If not, you'll need to setup the Home app on your phone to have access to the same account that you're developing with or permit and develop with the same account on your Home app.